# Python compare two different CSV Files which values are not in the same rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 CSV File which are looking like that:

first.csv (MasterFile)

```
Test1  10
Test2  20
```

second csv

```
Test8  80
Test1  10
```

In this case i'd like to create a function which says if value (Test8) in second.csv doesn't exists in first.csv print False.

My Code:

```
def checkContent():
    masterFile= pd.read_csv('./first.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
    df1=pd.DataFrame(masterFile, columns=[1])
    customerFile=pd.read_csv('.second.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
    df2=pd.DataFrame(customerFile, columns=[0])

    df1[1] = df2[0]
    check=np.where(df1[1]==df2[0], True, False)
    print(check)
```

But it just compares the first row. Not the other rows. I know that it has to be done by `row += 1` or something like that

Comment: Will there be only zero or exactly one entries in each CSV file for Test1?

Comment: You just gave one line of data. Please give 5 lines of dummy data and then explain what you expect for that data as the result.

Comment: I have to files like:

Article Definition<br/>
111     Product1<br/>
222     Product2<br/>
333     Product3<br/>
444     Product4<br/>

This is my masterlist<br/>

Now, let say i have another list: <br/>
Article Definition<br/>
111  Product1<br/>
222  Product2<br/>
555 Product5<br/>

I would like to compare the second list with my masterlist. As you can see there is the article 555 in my second List but not in my masterlist. In this case my code shoud 'break'. If alle article in my second list are available in the masterlist it should print me for example : True.

Answer (score 1):

`IIUC` you need a left join with `indicator = True`

```
check = np.where(pd.merge(df2,df1,on=['A','B'],how='left'
         ,indicator=True)['_merge'] == 'left_only',
         False,
         True)

print(check)
array([False,  True])
```

---

```
print(pd.merge(df2,df1,on=['A','B'],how='left',indicator=True))

       A   B     _merge
0  Test8  80  left_only
1  Test1  10       both
```